# How Can I Migrate an existing Windows VM workload to Kubernetes?

Tags: .net, windows, kubernetes

I just started researching Kubernetes. I have 2 Windows VM on hyper-v. One is a SQL server and one is an application server with a .net application. How can I migrate my SQL and APP servers to Kubernetes in an architecture so that applications can continue to run at the time of failover or down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in an architecture so that applications can continue to run at the time of failover or down.

To achieve this, you need to make sure that you don't have any single point of failure. Kubernetes is well architected for this kind of workload.

> an application server with a .net application

For this to run well in a container, it would be good to rewrite your app so it is run as a single process. This can be done in many different ways, but see e.g. [Build ASP.NET Core applications deployed to Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/build-aspnet-core-applications-linux-containers-aks-kubernetes).

> a SQL server

This is more challenging, since older relational database systems are architected for *single node systems*. It is easiest to run this **outside** your Kubernetes cluster, but with network access from your cluster. If you really want to run your relational database system in Kubernetes, you should use a **distributed database system**, e.g. [CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/) that has a PostgreSQL-like SQL syntax and is designed to run in a Kubernetes.